# VaR of protfolio with put and call

Tags: value-at-risk, call, put

I've stumbbled into this question in a job interview and didn't know how to answer it:

Calculate the VaR of a portfolio where you are long put and long a call

Comment: I don't know the answer immediately, but as a first step I would think "what are the scenarios where you lose money when you have such a position. What is the worst scenario". This is straightfoward.

Comment: Assume strikes, simplify to X(C)=X(P)=S_0. Then you cannot lose more than your initial outlay. VAR will be ‚a Little Bit‘ less than That.